# Smooks: How to process segments in varying order in EDI X12?

Tags: edi, smooks, x12

I am working with Smooks to process receiving EDI messages from different vendors.  I am using ejc to read the messages to get from EDI -> Java.  The problem I am having is that one provider is having a segment in a different order as the rest in their EDI message.

I would hate to basically have to duplicate all of the domain code, configuration, and branch the process just to handle one segment appearing in a different order.  How can I have Smooks not care about the specific order the segments are in while processing EDI -> Java via ejc?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh .... I think the only option you have is if you can somehow define these different variations in the edi mapping model schema used to generate the Java object model.

Comment: What I did is copy and paste the segment definition multiple times in the mapping with a min of 0 to get around this.  Is this really the best way to achieve this?